# Alternate to using if -else statements

Tags: c#, design-patterns

What is the best alternative for a if --else if --block that contains many if statements.

code:

```
 string word="";

 if(letter=='a')
    {
       // do some action
       call(a);
    } 
 else if (letter=='b')
   {

           call(b)
   }

 else if (letter=='c')
   {
       call(c)
   }
 else if (letter=='d')
   {
       // do some action
       call(d)
   }
 else if (letter=='e')
   {
       // do some action
       call(e)
   }

    ................

     ..............

 else if (letter=='z')
   {
       // do some action
        call(z)
   }
```

If there are many if-else statements what is the best way to find a solution for such a scenario. Is there a way to effectively design such a scenario using classes/objects?

I am sure many of us would have faced such problems like this during design/coding. Is there a effective way to handle such a situation?

NO SWITCH STATEMENTS PLEASE. AN EFFECTIVE DESIGN ALGORITHM USING C# OBJECTS WOULD BE THE BEST BET.

Comment: Could you say *why* you don't want to use `switch`?

Comment: If you're really against a switch statement, then your refactoring will have to do with logic more so than structure.

Comment: I am looking out for a design pattern which will solve this type of many if -else if - statements problem. Switch statements has its own limitation.

Comment: @Venkat, are you able to modify the source code of the objects that the algorithm examines?  This makes a significant difference.

Comment: Yes I will be able to modify the source code.

Comment: @Venkat, in that case consider the **virtual method** approach.  Add a virtual method to the common base type of the objects you're examining,  override it in each subtype to handle the logic distinct to each case, then simply call the virtual method and the runtime will dispatch it to the correct subtype's implementation.

Comment: Can you please put a skeleton structure for the above discussed problem. This will help others too.,

Answer (score 6):

In C# the **most direct** translation is a `switch` statement.  While `switch` is not strictly speaking an object-oriented construct, `char` is not a proper object in C# either.

```
switch(letter)
{
    case 'a':
        call(a);
        break;

    case 'b':
        call(b);
        break;

    // and so on
}
```

If the parameter is not a simple value type but rather an object, use a **virtual method** instead of an explicit control structure.  This is the true "object oriented" way to do it: in Smalltalk, `ifTrue:`, `ifFalse:` and `ifTrue:ifFalse:` are methods on `Boolean` taking code blocks as parameters!  C# makes this rather verbose, though.

```
static class Example {
    static void Sample(ISpeaker input) {
        input.Speak(); // this call acts like a control structure
    }
}

interface ISpeaker {
    void Speak();
}

class Cat : ISpeaker {
    public void Speak() {
        Console.WriteLine("Meow");
    }
}

class Dog : ISpeaker {
    public void Speak() {
        Console.WriteLine("Woof");
    }
}
```

If you are stuck with a simple type, another approach is an explicit **dispatch table**.

```
static readonly Dictionary<char, Action> dispatch
    = new Dictionary<char, Action> {
        { 'a', () => call(a) },
        { 'b', () => call(b) },
    };

static void Process(char letter) {
    dispatch[letter]();
}
```

If your conditions are too complex for a `Dictionary`-based dispatch table, you can use a `List`-based **linear dispatch table** which more closely mirrors the behavior of else-if chains:

```
static List<KeyValuePair<Func<char, bool>, Action>> dispatch
    = new List<KeyValuePair<Func<char, bool>, Action>>() {
        { x => x == 'a', () => call(a) },
        { x => x == 'b', () => call(b) },
        { x => true, () => callDefault() },
    };

static void Process(char letter) {
    dispatch.First(kvp => kvp.Key(letter)).Value();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
private Dictionary<char, Action> _dic =
    new Dictionary<char, Action>
    {
        {'a', (Action)a},
        {'b', (Action)b},
        ...
    };
```

And then

```
var action = this._dic.TryGetValue(letter);
if (action == null)
{
    // this is like default case - no key matched the letter
}
else
{
    // call the action associated with the letter
    action();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx

Do you mean a switch?  This is effectivly like a large list of else-ifs

Answer (score 1):

Use `switch` as an alternative to `if...else`.

`switch` offers more readability of your code and is more easy to understand rather that if else where, if you are nesting heavily, it might get difficult to understand and read code.

Also, `switch` is slightly better on the performance side when compared to `if...else`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you picked a more complex way to express a switch statement. Switch statements, in turn, [may be considered a "code smell"](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/switch-statements).

If I understand your example correctly, you really only want to vary a parameter on a method call based on the value of some variable. There might not be any good way to improve upon writing your code as switch statement, but maybe using a Dictionary to look up the parameter based on the `letter` value is an option to consider.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch statement.

```
switch (letter)
{
    case 'a':
        case(a);
        break;
    case 'b':
        case(b);
        break;
    ...
    case 'z':
        case(z);
        break;
    default:
        Assert.Fail(letter.ToString() + " was an unexpected value");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a switch statement:

```
switch(value)
{
     case value == "X":
          // handle
          break;
     case ...
           break;
    default:
           // Doesn't match any case above 
           break:
}
```